# Matlab 3D Plot with constraint

Tags: plot, constraints

i want to plot something like this:

3*x*y

with a constraint

x^2+y^2=8

in Matlab, so it should look like this:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+3xy+on+x%C2%B2%2By%C2%B2%3D8

any ideas?

i tryed

```
ezsurf(@(x,y)3*x.*y)
hold
fimplicit(@(x,y)x.^2+y.^2-8)
```

but the result is bad, the line plot doesn't follow the surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it!

```
a=@(x,y)3*x.*y
b=@(x,y)x.^2+y.^2-8
constpl(a,b)
```

and constpl is my own defined function

```
function constpl(fun,constraint)
a=fimplicit(constraint);
x=a.XData;
y=a.YData;
z=fun(x,y);
ind=z>=max(z)-0.000001;
x1=x(ind);
y1=y(ind);
z1=z(ind);
ezmesh(fun);
hold on
plot3(x,y,z,'r','LineWidth',2)
scatter3(x1,y1,z1,'rd','LineWidth',3)
hold off
end
```